# R RODBC sqlUpdate or sqlQuery

Tags: r, rodbc

I am trying to insert a dataframe into a sql table.
The `sqlUpdate` code gives a  inherits(channel, "RODBC") channel is missing error `Insertdata<-sqlUpdate(DBcon, df, tablename = "DataQuality", sqlColumns(special=FALSE))`
My second attempt was this

```
Insertdata<-sqlQuery(DBcon,paste("insert into DataQuality", df, sep = ""))
```

sqlQuery shows an error of

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near
>   'Nothing to add'

." (this is the first column and row of data)

> "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'insert into
>   DataQuality(Descriptions,Date,Name,Ref)SELECT
>   Descriptions,Date,Name,Ref FROMc(\"Nothing to add\"

, and seems to stop at the end of the first column.

Comment: Did you try to use [sqlSave](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf)? Per the docs: *sqlSave saves the data frame
dat in the table tablename.  If the table exists and has the appro-
priate structure it is used, or else it is created anew.*

Comment: I thought `sqlSave` was for creating a new table I am not sure how I would use this to insert into a table? when I try  `Insertdata<-sqlSave( DBcon, df, "DataQuality")` I get the error saying the table already exists.

Comment: Use the *append=True* argument.

Comment: I tried using `append=TRUE` but it crashes R. I have seen this post on[SqlSave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913664/rodbc-error-sqlsave-unable-to-append-to-table).

Comment: I managed to find out why, I needed rownames=FALSE. my final code that worked was `Insertdata<-sqlSave( DBcon, df, "DataQuality",rownames=FALSE, append=TRUE)`Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Insertdata<-sqlSave( DBcon, df, "DataQuality",rownames=FALSE, append=TRUE)`
This will update the SQL table with the new dataframe.